# stored procedures that counts specific users

Tags: sql

I have in dataBase table Users with

```
 FrendsInvited  FrendsCame  PromouterId
 10                5           32
 12                7           25
 7                 5           32
 10                8           47
 8                 7           25
```

I need to get all FriendsCame(number) from  all PromouterId.
that mean i need to get from.

```
 PromouterId 32=10 FriendsCame
 PromouterId 25=14 FriendsCame
 PromouterId 47=8  FriendsCame
```

how can i do this with store procedure?(or some thing else)
thanks.

Comment: Use the sum of the FriendsCame value and groupby using PromoterID

Comment: ***WHAT*** RDBMS is this for? Stored procedures are highly vendor-specific - and *SQL* is just the structured query language, used by many many database systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SUM` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT PromouterId, SUM(FrendsCame)
FROM table
GROUP BY PromouterId;
```

The SQL [`GROUP BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause groups together some tuples based on the specified columns (`PromouterId`), and performs an aggregate (`SUM`) over all tuples in a group. In addition to `SUM`, you may also use `AVG` (average), `COUNT`, `MIN`, `MAX` as aggregates.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straight forward. The key here is to use an *aggregate* function called `SUM()` to sum up the total value for every `PromouterId`.

```
SELECT  PromouterId, SUM(FrendsCame) TotalFrendsCame
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY PromouterId
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69cd9/1)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ PROMOUTERID ║ TOTALFRENDSCAME ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════════╣
║          25 ║              14 ║
║          32 ║              10 ║
║          47 ║               8 ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════════╝
```